# Detect if sql database has the following: Found non-empty schema 'foobar' without metadata table

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

If I run a certain test suite in our codebase, I end up with the this error when I try to start our spring boot app:

```
Caused by: com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Found non-empty schema 'foobar' without metadata table! Use init() first to initialize the metadata table.
```

I have a script which resolves this and makes the db be in a good state. Then I can start the app.

I want to detect this state and run this script automatically as part of the run configuration for the app.

In the java code I have access to java.sql.Connection.

Can I with this connection object detect this issue?

I tried inspecting connection.getMetadata() and connection.getSchema(). And also connection.getMetadata.getSchemas(). But everything I've checked so far seem to be the same for the state when everything is fine and when I receive the FlyWay error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foobar.flyway_schema_history")) {
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
    if (!(rs.next() && rs.getInt(1) > 0)) {
        // metadata table does not exist, run script to resolve the issue
        // run your script
    }
    // start Spring Boot application
}
```

This code checks if your metadata table exists. `If` not, run your script.

Comment: Perfect! The table was not named exactly like that, but it was easy enough to find, thank you.